# Proof that the integral of the principal part is equal to the residue

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to understand whats presented in Stein and Shakarchi, that the integral of the principal part is the residue:
[image: page1]

I don't understand how the last integral was arrived at.
I have that all other terms with order strictly greater than 1 have primitives, so they go to zero over C.

How did he arrive at $\frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_C P(z) dz = a_{-1}$?

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier, I would be grateful for an answer. Yes she is saying $\frac{a_{1}}{(z-z_0)^1}$ has no primitive. The integrals $\frac{1}{z}$, $\frac{1}{z^2}$ etc. have primitives.

Comment: $\int_C \frac{1}{z} dz$ =$i  |C$. $\int_C \frac{1}{z^2} dz$ = $\frac{-1}{z}  |C$ @ShiveringSoldier

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier. Thank you. Now I see $\frac{1}{z}$ has no primitive, because $F=i$ and $F'=0$. whereas for if $F=\frac{1}{z}$ then $F'=\frac{1}{z^2}$. And I can see I can use the log function as well to arrive at the $\int_C \frac{1}{z}$. I will see how I can apply the Cauchy integral formula. I am self-taught.

Comment: I thought of applying cauchy's integral formula and I see that I get $p(z) =\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \frac{a_{-1}}{(\zeta - z_{0})(z-\zeta)} d\zeta$. If  $a_{-1}$, has no primitive, how do I proceed further? @ShiveringSoldier

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier I would say it is zero, because f(z) has a pole at $z_{0}$, so it is not holomorphic there, and thats why its zero. Am I right?

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you.